# Focusing on DatePicker does not work MAUI

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, maui

I found that DatePicker is missing a Placeholder. It was decided in cases where the date is not specified - to display Label instead of DatePicker. However, when clicking on Label I need to open DatePicker, but it doesn't work

**.xaml:**

```
<controls:DatePickerWithoutBottomLine
    x:Name="datePicker"
    IsVisible="{Binding DisplayWeddingDate, Mode=TwoWay}"
    Date="{Binding WeddingDate, Mode=TwoWay}" />

<Label
    IsVisible="{Binding NotDisplayWeddingDate}"
    Text="some text">

    <Label.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped" />
    </Label.GestureRecognizers>
</Label>
```

**.xaml.cs:**

```
private void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, TappedEventArgs e)
{
    var label = (Label)sender;
    var datePicker = this.FindByName<DatePicker>("datePicker");
    label.IsVisible = false;
    datePicker.IsVisible = true;
    datePicker.Focus();
}
```

**viewmodel.cs:**

```
public partial class HomePageViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private DateTime? weddingDate;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private bool displayWeddingDate;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private bool notDisplayWeddingDate;

    private readonly PlanningService planningService;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private bool isRefreshing;

    public HomePageViewModel(PlanningService planningService)
    {
        this.planningService = planningService;

        InitAsync();
    }

    public override async void InitAsync()
    {
        await RefreshAsync();
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    private async Task RefreshAsync()
    {
        WeddingDate = await planningService.GetWeddingDateAsync();

        DisplayWeddingDate = WeddingDate.HasValue;
        NotDisplayWeddingDate = !DisplayWeddingDate;

        IsRefreshing = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found a way to open the date picker, Android's native View class (Android.Views) have a method called PerformClick which allows opening the date picker without pressing the DatePicker and TimePicker, I leave you an example of how I did it in case it can help someone in the same situation.

I have made a small example in which I have a DatePicker, when the user clicks on it the date picker appears, when we select a date from the picker and click "OK" the DateSelected event is fired and this is where the magic is done to access the TimePicker Handler and thus be able to access the native "PerformClick" method to open the TimePicker time selector without having to click on it:

**XAML:**

```
<StackLayout
    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
    <DatePicker 
        x:Name="datePicker"
        DateSelected="datePicker_DateSelected"
        BackgroundColor="White"
        TextColor="Black"
        FontSize="20"
        WidthRequest="200"
        HeightRequest="200">
    </DatePicker>

    <TimePicker 
        x:Name="timePicker"
        IsVisible="False"/>
</StackLayout>
```

**Code-behind:**

```
    private void datePicker_DateSelected(object sender, DateChangedEventArgs e)
    {
#if ANDROID
        var handler = timePicker.Handler as ITimePickerHandler;
        handler.PlatformView.PerformClick();
#endif
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the datepicker has IsVisible false, it's not part of the visual tree. There is no datePicker there to focus.

```
datePicker.IsVisible = true;
datePicker.Focus();
```

Try using this.Dispatcher.Dispatch to delay focus and give it a bit of time to be rendered.

```
        datePicker.IsVisible = true;
        this.Dispatcher.Dispatch(() =>
        {
            datePicker.Focus();
        });
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but unfortunately it didn't work

Comment: Sorry I thought a visualement could be focussed. I'm more experienced with wpf though. I don't think you can just set isfocusable=true in maui like wpf.

Comment: That's what I thought of first, but DatePicker.IsFocused has only a getter

Comment: Isfocused tells you whether it's focussed.  In wpf you can force controls to allow themselves to take focus by setting focusable true.  I don't see anything like that on maui visualelement or element though.

Comment: As a test, what happens if DatePicker has `IsVisible="True"` in xaml? I realize you don't want it to be visible right away, but if `datePicker.Focus()` works in that situation, then it is a place to start, for figuring out how to adapt this answer. Maybe a longer delay before focus.

Comment: That's an idea. You could try making the anonymous method async ( async before the round brackets)  and await Task.Delay(1000); before the focus to introduce a second delay.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue on Github: [Fix (or don't) the behavior of calling "Focus" on Android to open the picker](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/8946) . From the comment , Ghostbird said *the code that opens the picker has been removed from the Focus() method*. So we could not use Focus() method to open the datepicker any more.